# Need this to work with a button press

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code on this site that works for what I'm trying to do with a sign out log with one exception - it works as a worksheet update function right now and I need it to only work when a button is pressed. How would I modify this code so that it can be a macro that would be assigned to a button? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
       For Each r In Inte
            If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True End Sub
```

Comment: And is it still supposed to work on the current Selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep checking for values in column A only, then

```
Sub clickMe()
    Dim A As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Selection)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       For Each r In Inte
            If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            End If
        Next r
End Sub
```

If the column does not matter and the button should enter a date to the right of the selected cell, then

```
Sub clickMe()
    Dim r As Range
       For Each r In Selection
            If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            End If
        Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, this is much much closer to what I need and I apologize for not being clearer - but I need to do this across a range of cells in column A. So for example - I may have invoice numbers entered in Column A, Rows 2 through 20. When I click the button, I need the date added to column B for each cell where there is a value in Column A (so B2 through 20). If it matters, the current selected cell will always be at the cell below the last invoice in the list, so A21 in my example. The date then needs to go into B2-20 when they push the button.

Comment: Where is your own effort in this? The code above has enough detail that you can adjust it easily to loop through a fixed range, check the cell content, enter a date in the next cell if it is not empty. All elements are there. Just re-arrange them as you need. This is not a free code writing service.